# .gitignoring pdf file only when a tex source is present

Tags: git, version-control, tex

I'd like to set up a global `.gitignore` file in my home suitable for working with TeX files. So typical TeX junk files such as `*.log`, `*.aux`, `*.synctex.gz` would go in it.

The next step, however, is ignoring the compiled `somefile.pdf` if the source file `somefile.tex` is present. So my question is:

*Is there a syntax in `.gitignore` that I can use to tell it to ignore `somefile.pdf` only if `somefile.tex` is present?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't see this feature in [`gitignore` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore).

I would rather:

- ignore all `*.pdf` in your global `.gitignore` file
- run periodically a script updating a `.gitignore` file in any directory where a `pdf` file is found without a matching `.tex` file

  !afile.pdf

That would make the '`afile.pdf`' *not* ignored in that specific directory.

Comment: Not the answer that I hoped for, but "no" is still an answer. Accepting this, thanks.